# sql query to return values of dated18 months from now in a single row

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table with 12 periods(months) as described bellow:

```
CREATE TABLE  "FORECAST_DATA" (
   "COMPANY_CODE" NUMBER(6,0), 
   "CAT" VARCHAR2(30), 
   "PRODUCT_CODE" VARCHAR2(30), 
   "CUSTOMER_CODE" VARCHAR2(30), 
   "CYEAR" VARCHAR2(30), 
   "CHANNEL" VARCHAR2(30), 
   "P_1" NUMBER(6,0), 
   "P_2" NUMBER(6,0), 
   "P_3" NUMBER(6,0), 
   "P_4" NUMBER(6,0), 
   "P_5" NUMBER(6,0), 
   "P_6" NUMBER(6,0), 
   "P_7" NUMBER(6,0), 
   "P_8" NUMBER(6,0), 
   "P_9" NUMBER(6,0), 
   "P_10" NUMBER(6,0), 
   "P_11" NUMBER(6,0), 
   "P_12" NUMBER(6,0), 
   "FORECAST_COST" NUMBER(6,0)
   )
```

This table is used for forecasting, assuming the current date is Feb 2013, I want to write a query that returns 18 periods( P_2 to P_12 in 2013 plus P_1 to  P_7 in 2014) in a single row.

Thank you,

Sabe

Comment: Good news, this is doable (I've done it before, over a 13-period retail calendar, where period 1 was sometimes in August and sometimes in September)!  Bad news, it requires dynamic SQL!  Depending on your volume of rows, you may be able to normalize your database (get a `period` column) and then a list-aggregating function.  What's with the `FORECAST_COST` column - do you forecast cost for the entire year (I guess volatility depends on commodity).

Comment: Yes it is doable and I did use the dynamic SQL, the issue is the response time that's why I'm looking for a way to do it in pure SQL. FORECAST_COST is the product cost, and yes I forecast cost for the entire year.

Comment: The other bad news is that dynamic SQL is likely to have the _best_ performance, and be the easiest to conceptualize/maintain.  What are some basic statistics of your data - number of rows, indices, etc?  A 1 billion row table is going to eat processing time no matter how you write your query.  And give us an example dynamic query, too.

Comment: Clockwork-Muse, I posted the function below. You can have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

Use `ADD_MONTHS` function to get as many columns as you want. Something like this

```
SELECT sysdate, 
       ADD_MONTHS(sysdate,1) P_2,
       ADD_MONTHS(sysdate,2) P_3,
       ADD_MONTHS(sysdate,3) P_4,
       ADD_MONTHS(sysdate,4) P_5
FROM   dual;
```

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer, but not in this context, P_1 - P_12 are column names with numeric values, I want to return those numberic values. Your answer did help me though with other problem I have.

Comment: Ok, what do you expect in the columns? When you say that "return 18 periods", what exactly is the output your're expecting. Can you give an example?

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding, P_1 contains the number of sales made in period 1(January for this matter) for a particular product. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
function after_current_date(p_months_before number,p_current_month number, p_year number, p_product_code varchar2, p_category varchar2, p_channel varchar2) return number
as
        v_qty number;
        v_quert_stmt  varchar2(4000);
begin

        v_quert_stmt := 'select sum(qty_'||case when p_current_month + p_months_before > 12 
                                                       then case when p_current_month + p_months_before > 24 then
                                                                      p_current_month + p_months_before - 24
                                                                 else p_current_month + p_months_before - 12
                                                            end     
                                                  else p_current_month + p_months_before 
                                             end 
                    ||') from forecast_data_1
                        where cyear        = :bind_year
                         and product_code = :bind_product
                         and cat          = :bind_cat
                         and channel      = case :bind_channel when '||'''%'''||' then channel 
                                                               else :bind_channel end';

    execute immediate v_quert_stmt
    into v_qty
    using case when p_current_month + p_months_before > 12 then case when p_current_month + p_months_before > 24 then p_year + 2
                                                                    else p_year + 1
                                                                end
              else p_year  end,
          P_Product_Code, 
          P_Category,
          p_channel,
          p_channel;

    Return  V_Qty;
end after_current_date;
```

Comment: This should have been posted as an edit to your question, but I think I've spotted a potential problem: the `CASE` statement in your `WHERE` clause is probably invalidating use of any indices (and is potentially being evaluated for every row).  Your statement is already dynamic, simply leave off that condition - note that a leading wildcard (`%`) will _also_ ignore indices.  This query also appears to be referencing columns/tables _not_ in your question (as if they might be part of a view?) - is this just a typographical difference, or is there something more?

Comment: Thank you  Clockwork-Muse, the referenced columns/tables in the original question is a "typo". as for the CASE statement in my WHERE clause, I will try to eliminate it(CASE) but the condition must be there. I will update as soon as I get something new.